# Cannot see the y-values in facet_wrap using ggplot

Tags: r, database, ggplot2

Looking at the Carseats data in the ISRL package, creating a barchart. The x-value will be a factor, ShelveLoc, and each chart represents each column in the data set. The head of the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ISLR)
head(Carseats)

  Sales CompPrice Income Advertising Population Price ShelveLoc Age Education Urban  US
1  9.50       138     73          11        276   120       Bad  42        17   Yes Yes
2 11.22       111     48          16        260    83      Good  65        10   Yes Yes
3 10.06       113     35          10        269    80    Medium  59        12   Yes Yes
4  7.40       117    100           4        466    97    Medium  55        14   Yes Yes
5  4.15       141     64           3        340   128       Bad  38        13   Yes  No
6 10.81       124    113          13        501    72       Bad  78        16    No Yes
```

Plotting ShelveLoc vs the other columns works to print the graphs, but does not show the y-values:

```
ISLR::Carseats %>% 
  gather(-ShelveLoc,  key = "var", value = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ShelveLoc, y = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~var, scales = "free")
```

Here is what it looks like - the bar charts are fine, but the y-values are not clear.

[image]

How can the y-values be displayed clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a class issue. By using `gather` you do not get an Error. Using the newer `pivot_longer` will give you the error:

```
Error in `pivot_longer()`:
! Can't combine `Sales` <double> and `Urban` <factor<afba0>>.
```

to overcome mutate all but `ShelveLoc` to `numeric`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ISLR)

Carseats %>% 
  mutate(across(-ShelveLoc, as.numeric)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ShelveLoc, names_to = "var", values_to = "value") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = ShelveLoc, y = value)) +
    geom_col() +
    facet_wrap(~var, scales = "free")
```

[image]